# Using Zoom H1 recorder as a micro, is it possible to change the default behavior when connect it to PC?

Tags: usb, audio, microphone, audio-recording

I use voice recorder Zoom H1 as a PC USB microphone. When I connect the recorder to my PC (Windows 8.1 x64), recorder asks what I want - to use it as a memory card (access to their memory) or as a audio card/micro. The first behavior is default. Always, when I shutdown my PC and then turn on it, I must to pick needed behavior. If I don't do it, recorder works as a memory card. Is it possible to change default behavior? Any patches, custom firmware, etc?

Comment: Super old question I know, but did you ever figure this out? I'm wondering the same thing.

Comment: I contacted the developer (ZOOM), but they said it's not possible. They did not provide the source code for the firmware for self-change. I assume that it is may be possible to save the settings with external power for the recorder, but I haven't tested this.